# How to programmatically filter columns in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

How would I create a function that drops NA values in a column if I don't want to specify the column until the function is called?

```
minimal_case <- function(column_name = "a") {
  enquo_name <- enquo(column_name)

  example <- tibble(a = c(NA, 1))

  print(filter(example, !is.na(a)))

  print(filter(example, !is.na(rlang::UQ(enquo_name))))

}
```

The output of the first print statement is:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
      a
  <dbl>
1     1
```

The output of the second print statement is:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 1
      a
  <dbl>
1    NA
2     1
```

How do I get the second print statement to match the first?

Comment: `function(df, x) df[!is.na(df[[x]]), ]`

Comment: If you're providing a string as the column name, you're using standard evaluation and can skip the whole tidyeval business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the `column_name` parameter is a string. In that case, you can use `rlang::sym`:

```
minimal_case <- function(column_name = "a") {
    example <- tibble(a = c(NA, 1))

    print(filter(example, !is.na(a)))

    print(filter(example, !is.na(!!rlang::sym(column_name))))

}
```

Comment: Very helpful to refer to `rlang`; I had seen the quosure stuff for `dplyr` but `rlang::sym` looks like a straightforward way to transition functions that use the old style e.g. `mutate_` calls to quosures.

Comment: dplyr will soon export `sym()` as well. The functionalities of `sym()` and quosures are complementary.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good write-up on how to do things like this in dplyr here: http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

The punchline for this case is that you don't have to quote `a` in the parameters. You can also use `!!` instead of `UQ`

```
minimal_case <- function(column_name = a) {
    enquo_name <- enquo(column_name)

    example <- tibble(a = c(NA, 1))

    print(filter(example, !is.na(a)))

    print(filter(example, !is.na(!!enquo_name)))

}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call that variable `column_name` because "column names" makes me think of strings, e.g. the output of `colnames()`. Also in your version it's not necessarily a column symbol, it could be an expression too.